# Как починить таймер обратного отсчёта?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Registration closes in <span id="time"><span id='time0'>05</span>:<span id='time1'>00</span>:<span id='time2'>00</span></span> minutes!</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">


function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, hours, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
      hours = parseInt(timer / 3600, 10);
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        time0.textContent = hours;
        time1.textContent = minutes;
        time2.textContent = seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 3600 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы это чудо заработало?

Comment: Починить можно с помощью [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Registration closes in <span id="time"><span id='time0'>05</span>:<span id='time1'>00</span>:<span id='time2'>00</span></span> minutes!</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">


function startTimer(secs, display) {
    var seconds = secs, date;
    setInterval(function () {
        date = new Date(seconds*1000);
        time0.textContent = ("0" + date.getUTCHours()).slice(-2);
        time1.textContent = ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
        time2.textContent = ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

        if (--seconds < 0) {
            seconds = secs;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 300,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```